# Can I use Gmail for my email domain?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I use my own domain for email, so that I can use multiple email addresses when shopping online, subscribing, etc.

These are all redirected to Gmail.

I have created some addresses under that domain for use when sending in Gmail.

What I would like to do is send mail without the need to register each address separately, or create a new email address in "Google Apps for your domain".

Is there a method to register the whole domain with Gmail so that I can send email in this way without needing to verify a new address?

[Original answers suggested Google Apps for your domain.  I didn't known about this, and I think it will be useful for me, but it doesn't obviously allow this feature.]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes - use [Google Apps for Your Domain](http://www.google.com/apps/).

It's free for up to 50 users.

[Free GAFYD](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) (as provided by [Tobbe](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/1554/tobbe) below)

**UPDATE** This answer is no longer valid if you don't already have a Google Apps account. Google Apps is no longer free for new signups!! (Thanks to [asalamon74](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/1509/asalamon74) for the update)

Comment: Are you sure you can only have 50 free users? I used it a 2 years ago and have more than 100 accounts.

Comment: They keep decreasing it for new registrations. I still have 100, so old accounts remain as are.

Comment: @itsabout: It's been dropping. My main account, which I registered  a few years ago, has 200 users. The new domain I registered last week has only 50.

Comment: The free version is http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html as posted by Tobbe. I am setting this up now and will see whether it does what I want.

Comment: You can setup a catch all address in Google Apps for receiving email sent to a non-existent address, but you would need to do something to send from them via Google Apps.  Sending from a different client might work though depending on the mail server you are sending through.

Comment: It's no longer free for new signups.

Answer (score 10):

You can also just add "+foo" and "+bar" to distinguish your normal gmail address for each site. They will all go to your normal gmail address. For instance, if your name is bob@gmail.com, you can use "bob+amazon@gmail.com" and "bob+facebook@gmail.com", and so on.

Comment: -1 you cannot send FROM those addresses which is part of the OP's requirement

Comment: @Shevek: Yes you can, by setting them up as additional From addresses under Settings > Accounts. It's not ideal, but it is possible

Comment: You can do this, but there are many websites that you then can't use that email because they declare the format is invalid.  (I just mention this because that's how I used to track where the spam was coming from)

Comment: see my answer below to use "minus addressing" instead of "plus addressing" (which is often not supported...)

Answer (score 3):

In the time since this question was asked, the **free "Google Apps for your Domain" program has been discontinued**. The [current program](http://www.google.com/intx/en/enterprise/apps/business/index.html) costs $5 per month per user, or $10 per year per user. I still recommend this for my clients.

There does exist a workaround for having a **free** *single address* at a custom domain, using [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/?csw=1). This workaround is less intuitive and less flexible, but it works for those who insist on free Gmail-based webmail for **a single email address**.

The workaround is based on the fact that Google Apps Engine accounts also function as email addresses, and each Apps Engine account gets a single user for free. I discovered this workaround from [this Google Groups forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/pVZfdeky-ow/TO1SmipM2Y0J). Just sign up for Google App Engine, add your domain, and configure the single free account with an email address.