# Standard @gmail.com and separate domain user alias?

Tags: gmail

I have a domain name and have added the Gmail MX records to it. I understand I can use the *Send mail as* for sending mail and the POP3 for receiving, but I currently don't have a mail server and I would rather just have Google Mail receive my domain emails through an alias.

Is there a way I can have my regular `@gmail.com` also receive mail from my personal domain?

Comment: See this answer: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/61396/21583

Answer (score 1):

No, if you insist on associating Google-provided email with your personal domain, then you have no choice but to use Google Apps -- which, as you correctly pointed out, is no longer free today.

You might consider alternatives such as Microsoft's Outlook.com, or email packages offered by the various web-hosting providers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to organize all your email in one place, you could try to read emails from other accounts (under settings, accounts -> check mail from other accounts)

For sending email alias, you can do that on the same settings page: `send mail as`

Comment: as I said, I don't have a pop3 server (no mail server) and I know I can "send mail as" any valid email address that I own.  I want my user@gmail.com account to be an Alais of my @domain.com address.  But it seems Gmail no longer supports this free of charge.