# How can I setup Gmail with my custom domain email address?

Tags: gmail

I have an email of the type `myname@mydomain.com`, but I want to use it with my Gmail account. Let me explain.

I want to give people my `myname@mydomain.com` address, and all the email I receive there should be redirected to my Gmail inbox, so I can read it there.

This is simple. The problem is how to setup the opposite direction.

I also want to be able to reply to people or send email, using my Gmail account, but I want to send them from `myname@mydomain.com`

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use Gmail for my email domain?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2109/can-i-use-gmail-for-my-email-domain)

Comment: I don't think that it's a duplicate of [Can I use Gmail for my email domain?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2109/) because this quiestion is about a single account and already forwarded the email of the external account to Gmail.

Answer (score 3):

### Send mail from aliases in gmail

> 1. Click the gear in the top right .
> 2. Select Settings.
> 3. Click the Accounts and Import tab.
> 4. Under Send mail as, click Add another email address.
> 5. In the 'Email address' field, enter your name and alternate email address you own.
> 6. Enter the SMTP server (e.g. smtp.domain.com), your username on that domain, and your password for that account. You may also need to
>      adjust your port setting or SSL setting (talk to your other ISP if you
>      need this information).
> 7. Click Add account >>

[Learn more about 'Send mail from a different address or alias'.](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)

**Edited**

### Aliases in Mac Mail

> 1. Open the Mail application.
> 2. Select "Preferences" from the "Mail" menu in the upper-left
>      corner of the application window.
> 3. Click the name of the Mail account where you want to add
>      aliases. If you only have one account set up, it will select itself
>      automatically.
> 4. Click in the "Email Address" box on the Account Information
>      screen. Move your cursor to the end of the current contents.
> 5. Type a comma, then add the alias you want this account to have.
>      Repeat for additional aliases.
> 6. Click the red "X" button button in the upper-left of the window
>      to exit the Preferences. When prompted, click "Save" to save the
>      changes you made.
> 7. Click the "New Message" button in the Mail window. In the
>      "From" field, a drop-down menu appears that lists all the email
>      addresses available to this account, including the new aliases you
>      added. Select one of them, and the message will send from that alias
>      address instead of your Mac Mail account address.

[Learn more about Aliases in Mac Mail](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/send-email-aliases-mac-mail-45879.html)

Comment: perfect, it works, but if i do that from "mail" on mac, won't send the mail correctly